Unity (Vuforia) Black screen on some android devices 2024
on some Android devices, when I load the AR camera (Vuforia) Unity, it just shows a black screen. This issue occurs on certain ARCore-supported devices, even though the devices are listed as supported. Interestingly, it works on most ARCore devices and even on devices that do not support ARCore.
From what I understand, Vuforia has its own AR engine and is designed to work independently of ARCore on non-ARCore devices.
Has anyone experienced the same issue and found a solution? I’ve come across similar posts, but they are quite old, and the suggestions provided are no longer relevant. I have tried all combinations of ARCore requirements, along with other settings. Here are screenshots of my current configuration:




there is a known issue affecting Android devices https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/169 however this only happens when ARCore is not in use. Are you sure that Google Services for AR are installed on the device?

Yes, when I changed to build in renderer pipeline it worked on that device. But it is still not working on another device which is not ar core supported. From what I understand ARCore is not required

Correct it is not mandatory for most features (it is on AreaTargets). Still it is recommended if you want to enable extended tracking.

Yes, but I am only using image tracking and it is not working on non AR core devices

Looks like a fix is coming https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/149#issuecomment-2558371964
